# Java A3 printing on Macs coming out at A4 scale

Tags: java, macos, printing, awt

I have an odd problem that seems to be specific to Mac computers. I have a prog that prints the content of an AWT drawing surface to an A3 sheet of paper. On Linux and windows machines the output is OK. Printing from a Mac I get the same dialog with the same preset parameters, the printer prints on an A3 sheet of paper as expected, but for some reason the image is scaled to fit an A4 area. Below are the relevant sections of code:

```
public void print() {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
    format.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

    double margin = 18; // quarter inch
    double m2 = margin * 2;
    Paper paper = format.getPaper();
    paper.setSize(16.54 * 72, 11.69 * 72); // A3 Landscape
    paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin,  paper.getWidth()-m2, paper.getHeight()-m2);
    format.setPaper(paper);
    printJob.setPrintable(this, format);

    PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    attributes.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A3);
    attributes.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
    attributes.add(new MediaPrintableArea((int)margin, (int)margin,
            (int)(paper.getWidth()-m2), (int)(paper.getHeight()-m2),
            MediaPrintableArea.INCH));

    if(printJob.printDialog(attributes) ){
      try {
        printJob.print(attributes);
      } catch(PrinterException pe) {
        pe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) {
    if (pageIndex > 0) {
      return(NO_SUCH_PAGE);
    } else {
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
      g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
      if(this.componentToBePrinted instanceof PlannerView){
          setScale(g2d);
      }
      disableDoubleBuffering(componentToBePrinted);
      componentToBePrinted.paint(g2d);
      enableDoubleBuffering(componentToBePrinted);
      return(PAGE_EXISTS);
    }
  }

  public void setScale(Graphics2D g2d){
      PlannerView planner = (PlannerView)this.componentToBePrinted;
      planner.resetZoom();
      double scale = 1.0 / planner.getRowLength();
      scale *= 4.0; 
      g2d.scale(scale, scale);
  }
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Cheers.

Comment: Possibly related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3453

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
PageFormat newFormat =printJob.pageDialog(format);
```

before printing, the printer may modify the margins.

At least take a look in the debugger and see what it turns into.

Also note that the Macintosh native printing coordinate systems for landscape is inverted.

So maybe try it with REVERSE_LANDSCAPE instead of LANDSCAPE ( and it might be flipped, but may not get list in translation)

Answer (score 0):

Deal with setImageableArea(), change the values and try. Also apply reverse_landscape for mac.
And set the A3 size: 1190 & 842 not decimal values.