# How to change printing margins with JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm generating a report straight to printer, but am encountering some problems.  If I render it to screen and print the resulting PDF, it prints fine.  However, when I print directly, I get weird margin problems.  The target is a Zebra with 4"x3" labels.

If I set the paper size like so:

```
MediaSizeName mediaSizeName=MediaSize.findMedia(4, 3, MediaPrintableArea.INCH);
printRequestAttributeSet.add(mediaSizeName);
```

The result is a label up against the top margin, with a half inch left margin (should be none), the right margin is about .25" with part of the label chopped off, and the bottom maring is 1.5" with a lot of label chopped off.

If I don't set the paper size, then the top and left margins are perfect (meaning, there aren't any, goes to the edge of the label), but I still end up with the big bottom margin (with stuff chopped off), and my right margin gets a lot bigger (chopped off at the same point in regards to the printed information).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, after all this it turned out to be a printer preferences option on the system.  I can't explain why PDF printing from the screen worked.  I tried setting up a custom label stock, in the printer setup, with the 4"x3" size and that didn't help my Java app, so I figured it was something I was coding wrong.  Not so.  Apparently the custom label stock thing just doesn't work right.  I was able to dig down into advanced options and set the size there, and that works...

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use  `setBottomMargin, setTopMargin, setRightMargin, setLeftMargin` methods of [JasperDesign](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html) class or the same methods from [JasperPrint](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint.html) class.

You can see the sample [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/noxmldesign/index.html).

You can also set margins in report's template, for example with help of iReport.
The snippet of report template:

```
<jasperReport ... language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="593" leftMargin="1" rightMargin="1" topMargin="1" bottomMargin="1">
```

You can also look at the [MediaPrintableArea class constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaPrintableArea.html#MediaPrintableArea%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29) and read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768515/java-a3-printing-on-macs-coming-out-at-a4-scale).

***UPDATED:***

The another solution how to remove margins from [this discussion](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2008/01/17/print-a-pdf-document-in-java/):

```
    PageFormat pf = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
    Paper paper = new Paper();
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight()); // no margin = no scaling
    pf.setPaper(paper);
```

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately, it *is* set correctly there (I believe).  pageWidth=288.  72 per inch.  7 left and 7 right margin, largest item is 274 wide, for grand total of 288.  :-(

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Everything is ok when you print generated pdf file?

Comment: Generated PDF (via exportToPdfStream) comes out fine, nothing clipped.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Try this: PageFormat pf = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();

Paper paper = new Paper();
paper.setImageableArea(0,0,paper.getWidth(),paper.getHeight()); // no margin = no scaling
pf.setPaper(paper);

Comment: Despite not being the true answer to my exact situation, I learned a lot of good things from this answer and the resulting comments!  May well be the correct answer for other people that have the same symptoms!